# Running out of space using Xamarin on my PC

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019, diskspace

I created a Xamarin app on my PC (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019) along with an android emulator (Pixel Pie 9.0 -API 28).

I noticed when creating Xaml pages along with corresponding View Models and running the changes on the emulator consumes a conciderable amount of data on my drive.

I am new to Xamarin App/Android development so my guess is that there is caching of data (perhaps?) that takes up allot of space. Creating a Registration form for example, building and running the change on the emulator resulted in disk space dropping from 13.5 GB to 10 GB.

How can I free up data on my hard drive as at this rate it feels like it will run out very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of it is cache (mostly downloaded nuget packages), but a lot of it is also just the compiled app (the debug version of which is often a lot larger than a normal 'release' build). The emulator also consumes some space to create and run, which is not avoidable. Installing the android sdk and emulator images does not create the actual emulator disk image until you run the emulator itself.

In general, you should not expect to see the use of space continue to increase at that rate unless you run multiple versions of the emulator. Just adding new code to the same project shouldn't change the size much.

To free space temporarily, you can always delete the obj and bin folders in your project, but they will be recreated as soon as you build it again.

Comment: Great thanks. That makes sense. I continued with the way things are and the disk space 'stabilized' which is more or less what I expected and was hoping for :)